# how to use marquee kind of tag in facebook

Tags: facebook

Can anybody let me know how to implement marquee tag in facebook application as it seems facebook doesn't support the marquee tag.

Comment: Hello, is there anybody who can answer this ???

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe application and implement marquee in javascript.

take a look at this script:

[http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex…](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/cmarquee.htm)

Comment: No, I have fBML application only, Is there any way to do this in FBML.